# Xamarin Plugin.FirebasePushNotification causes app to go into break state

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin

The Xamarin Plugin.FirebasePushNotification causes my application to go into break mode, it was working but after I sent a few notifcations through the console then anytime I tried to run the app it would go into break mode and say an An unhandled exception occurred, it says your app has entered break state but there is no to code to show because all the threads were executing external code.

This is the code that is causing it in MainApplication.cs:

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();

    //If debug you should reset the token each time.
    #if DEBUG
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);
    #else
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);
    #endif

    //Handle notification when app is closed here
    CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
        {

        };
}
```

And then in Main Activity I have this line of code:

```
FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(Intent);
```

When I replace the google-services.json it works for a while and then randomly breaks again, I have no idea what the problem could be